# Typescript build issue with lerna

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig, lerna

I currently have a lerna/react/TS project of the following structure:

```
.
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── patient
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── index.tsx
│   │   ├── tsconfig.build.json
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── appointment
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       │   └── index.tsx
│       ├── tsconfig.build.json
│       └── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.build.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

In `packages/appointment/src/index.tsx` its importing the `patient` module:

```
import { Patient } from '@ui-sdk/patient';
```

when running the build command `tsc --project ./tsconfig.build.json` inside the `appointment` folder, its adding the `patient` code again.

Actual:

```
/packages/appointment/dist/patient/index.js
/packages/appointment/dist/appointment/index.js
```

Expected:

```
/packages/appointment/dist/index.js
```

The build config at the `/packages/appointment/tsconfig.build.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.build.json",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },

  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

and the main `tsconfig.json` at the root level:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@ui-sdk/*": ["packages/*/src"]
    },
  },

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

If I remove this section:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@ui-sdk/*": ["packages/*/src"]
    },
```

The compilation throws an error

```
packages/appointment/src/index.tsx(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ui-sdk/patient' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Any idea how to make the build contain only the codes for that component only, instead of bringing the other files in the build folder?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. The problem was that i had to omit the "paths" from the `tsconfig.build.json` file.

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends" "./tsconfig.build.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@ui-sdk/*": ["packages/*/src"]
    }
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.build.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This results in TS not trying to resolve you local packages and instead sees it as a reference to an external package.